# SET*5 set_config ------------ (1 row) SET*4 CREATE TABLE ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS" LINE 2: AS integer ^ Import error: exit status 3

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, pg-dump

I have been trying to import .sql file created from pg_dump into google's cloudsql. But I keep getting this error message:

```
 SET SET SET SET SET set_config ------------ (1 row) SET SET SET SET SET CREATE TABLE ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS" LINE 2: AS integer ^ Import error: exit status 3
```

Before this problem, I got stuck at EXTENSION COMMENT issue, so I did `pg_dump -U [USERNAME] --format=plain --no-owner --no-acl [DATABASE_NAME] \
    | sed -E 's/(DROP|CREATE|COMMENT ON) EXTENSION/-- \1 EXTENSION/g' > [SQL_FILE].sql` as Google's documentation recommends.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You are trying to restore a dump from v10 or later into an older version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's exactly the issue. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Laurenz Albe, if you are kind enough, is there any way to install the older version of postgres sq without breaking dependencies?

Comment: You'd have to ask Google if they are offering older versions. But why don't you upgrade the database before migrating it?